# How to extract all data of certain length starting with a certain pattern from a log file in Linux

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a log file (.txt format) in linux system. Want to extract all data starting with "1499" and write to another file. There are two types of data in the log, one type is 13 digit long and another type is 38 digit long.

I would like any suggestions of grep, sed or awk commands.

**Log file example:**

```
1499186243519, 36533, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1499186244816, 35237, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1499186244837, 35224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1499182567904?
1499182567982 -> 200 OK, 0 bytes
1499182568007?
14991855787919196616688454500234291584**
14991855788021403876667136479787697727**
14991855803593386396169567154870815462**
```

**The output should be looked like:**

```
1499186243519
1499186244816
1499186244837
1499182567904
1499182567982
1499182568007
14991855787919196616688454500234291584
14991855788021403876667136479787697727
14991855803593386396169567154870815462
```

Comment: You can produce the posted desired output from the posted sample input with just `sed 's/[^0-9].*//'` so if that's not all you need then that's not a good example as it wouldn't test that a potential solution actually does what you really need rather than just produces the expected output from the sample input. So if that's NOT all you need then update your example to more truly represent your real input so it can be used to test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep and extended regexp (`-E`):

```
grep -Eo -e '^1499[0-9]{9}' -e '^1499[0-9]{34}' file
```

Output:

```
1499186243519
1499186244816
1499186244837
1499182567904
1499182567982
1499182568007
14991855787919196616688454500234291584
14991855788021403876667136479787697727
14991855803593386396169567154870815462
```

Comment: Thanks Cyrus. I think this is the best solution I could take. Thanks to all for your contributions.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

```
$ echo "$log"
1499186243519, 36533, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1499186244816, 35237, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1499186244837, 35224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1499182567904?
1499182567982 -> 200 OK, 0 bytes
1499182568007?
14991855787919196616688454500234291584**
14991855788021403876667136479787697727**
14991855803593386396169567154870815462**
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$log" | sed -E 's/^(1499[[:digit:]]*).*$/\1/'
1499186243519
1499186244816
1499186244837
1499182567904
1499182567982
1499182568007
14991855787919196616688454500234291584
14991855788021403876667136479787697727
14991855803593386396169567154870815462
```

And this works too:

```
$ sed -E 's/^(1499[[:digit:]]*).*$/\1/' file
```

With `file` having that content...

Or `awk`:

```
$ echo "$log" | awk -F[^0-9] '/^1499/{print $1}'
```

Or grep:

```
$ echo "$log" | grep -o '^1499[[:digit:]]*'
```

Answer (score 0):

With Bash:

```
$ while read -r;do [[ $REPLY =~ ^1499[0-9]* ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH} >>new_log.txt;done <log.txt

$ cat new_log.txt
1499186243519
1499186244816
1499186244837
1499182567904
1499182567982
1499182568007
14991855787919196616688454500234291584
14991855788021403876667136479787697727
14991855803593386396169567154870815462
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU **awk** version, which prints numbers of length 13 or 38, even if there are ***more than one*** on the same line:

```
$ awk -v p="([[:digit:]]{38}|[[:digit:]]{13})" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if (match($i, p, a)) print a[1]}}' input.txt
```

with input:

```
$ cat input.txt
1499186243519, 36533, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14991855803593386396169567154870815462**
1499186244816, 35237, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1499186244837, 35224, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
1499182567904?
1499182567982 -> 200 OK, 0 bytes
1499182568007?
14991855787919196616688454500234291584**
14991855788021403876667136479787697727**
14991855803593386396169567154870815462**
```

which gives:

```
$ awk -v p="([[:digit:]]{38}|[[:digit:]]{13})" '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){ if (match($i, p, a)) print a[1]}}' input.txt
1499186243519
14991855803593386396169567154870815462
1499186244816
1499186244837
1499182567904
1499182567982
1499182568007
14991855787919196616688454500234291584
14991855788021403876667136479787697727
14991855803593386396169567154870815462
```

Answer (score 0):

**GREP COMMAND**

> grep -Eo "^([1][4][9][9][0-9]{1,13}|[1][4][9][9][0-9]{1,38})" abc.txt

Use -E to access the extended regular expression syntax

- Set -o to only output the matching segment of the line, rather than the full contents of the line

  ^ represents the starting of the string in the pattern.
  1499 is the string pattern to be fixed in the start after that any number can follow and the length can be 13 digit and 38 digit.

Comment: Thanks Anirudh. Your solution is close to Cyrus' solution.